# cant access magento admin panel when my site is in a subdirectory

Tags: php, magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.4

Hi I have magento website on a local host and it is working perfect, so I decide to move this over to a sub directory on my live server the front end is showing but when I sign into my admin panel I get a blank white screen.

I have cleared the cache 
I have turned on url rewrites 
all folders and files have the correct permissions

i am just wondering if i have done something wrong within the installation ?

any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: I have just done a trace on the problem within the index page and this is what i get Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/My.MainDirectory.co.uk/httpdocs/subdirectory/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 450

Comment: Take a look @ http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/access-admin-for-sub-directory-website

Comment: @R.S i did look at this and it was slightly help i found out it was a problem that i had created i was trying to connect a 1.4.0.0 file directory to a 1.4.1.1 database and when i used the correct directory version then this was no longer a problem. thanks for the help thou i will keep that post in mind for future dates due to this just being a test for me